# How to add data to selectAll placeholder whose data is in a parent's parent object?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Initially I have a flat hash structure from a csv that has the following fields:

```
zoneId,op,metricName,value
```

Then I nest it by

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){return d.zoneId})
  .key(function(d){return d.op})
  .entries(data)
```

Now it has a hierarchy that looks like

```
zoneId -> op -> <details>
```

Here is an example of the data

```
nestedData = {
[{
  "key": "zone1",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Get",
    "values": [{
      "zoneId":"zone1"
      "op":"Get"
      "metricName":"CompletionTime",
      "value":"10ms"
    }, {
      "zoneId":"zone1"
      "op":"Get"
      "metricName":"Throughput",
      "value":"100 query/s"
    }]
  },{
    /* Similar to the "values" of last bracket */
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "key": "zone2",
  "values": [
    /* Similar to the "values" of last bracket */
    ]
  }]
}]
}
```

Now I want to build a table from this nest data structure.

- Each zone occupies a table
- Each op is a row
- In each row

  - left column is the op name
  - Right column is a formatted version of metrics (such as: "10 ms @ 100 QPS")

**The problem is:**

How should I bind data to <tr> placeholders? Since the <table> has data but <tbody> does not when I append them to <table>, while the <tr> are under <tbody>.

```
var tables = d3.select('#perfs .metrics')
          .selectAll('table')
          .data(nestedData)
          .enter().append('table');
/* added tbody and data */
tables.append('tbody')
      .selectAll('tr')
      .data(???).enter()
      .append('tr')
      .selectAll('td')
      .data(function(d){return [d.key,d.value];})   // left and right column
      .enter().append('td')
      .text(function(d){ /* iterate through the metrics and format them */ })
```

Here are two solutions I can think of:

- Assign data to tbody(but sounds hacky!)
- Access the this.parentNode.__data__ (also sounds hacky!)

Can you give any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `selection.append()` in the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference), it reads:

> Each new element inherits the data of the current elements

In other words, `<tbody>` by default will have the same data which is bound to the `<table>`. So, your code would be:

```
var metrics = d3.select('#perfs .metrics');
var tables = metrics.selectAll('table').data(nestedData);
tables.enter().append('table');

var tbody = tables.append('tbody');
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr").data(function(d) { return d.values; });
rows.enter().append("tr");
var cells = rows.selectAll("td").data(function(d) { return d.values; });
cells.enter().append("td")
  .text(function(d){ /* iterate through the metrics and format them */ });
```